# Div tag's layering question

Tags: javascript, css, html, layer

Suppose i am having two Div layer

```
<div id="div1"> One </div>
<div id="div2"> Two </div>
```

I want them both to be overlapped

and when i click the Button 
i want that the Div1 layer to go in the background and the top layer should become Div2.

How can i achieve it through JavaScript ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `z-index` is being set with CSS then you need to get the computed style of the element, so getting `element.style.zIndex` directly won't work.  Since this is implemented differently in IE than in other browsers, let's make a function to get the computed style:

```
var getCompStyle = function( id ) {
    var curStyle;
    if (window.getComputedStyle) {
        curStyle = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById( id ), null);
    } else {
        curStyle = document.getElementById( id ).currentStyle;
    }
    return curStyle;
};
```

Once we have this function, we can then apply the `z-index` accordingly attached to a button click handler:

```
document.getElementById('switch').onclick = function(e) {
    var div1style = getCompStyle( 'div1' );
    var div2style = getCompStyle( 'div2' );
    var switcher = div1style.zIndex;
    document.getElementById('div1').style.zIndex = div2style.zIndex;
    document.getElementById('div2').style.zIndex = switcher;
};
```

I've created [a fiddle example here (link)](http://jsfiddle.net/NTAXZ/1/) to demonstrate.

Comment: How can i change the values of the button ? when the DIV 1 is being showed the value of the button is "1" and when 2nd Div is being shown the Value should be "2"

Comment: I've updated the example link to do this. Click again to see how this behavior is accomplished.

Answer (score 1):

Vertical positioning is controlled in CSS using the "z-index" parameter.  You can set this with javascript by accessing the element's "style" parameter.

Here's a full example, with comments indicating tricky spots to watch out for:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type='text/css'>
            .container {
               /* Needs explicit positioning for "absolute" positioning of
                  child elements to work properly */
               position: relative;
               /* Need to set height, because absolute-positioned child elements take up no space */
               height: 50px;
            }
            #div1, #div2 {
                position: absolute;
                left: 0;
                top: 0;
                width: 100px;
                height: 50px;
                /* without a background color, you'll see div1 through div2. */
                background-color: white;
                /* border makes it easier to see while testing */
                border: 1px solid red;
            }
        </style>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            function swapDivs() {
                var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
                var div2 = document.getElementById('div2');
                // swap zIndex values.
                var temp = div1.style.zIndex;
                div1.style.zIndex = div2.style.zIndex;
                div2.style.zIndex = temp;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='container'>
            <div id="div1" style='z-index: 0;'> One </div>
            <div id="div2" style='z-index: 1;'> Two </div>
        </div>
        <input id='switch' type='button' value='switch' onclick='swapDivs();' />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works !!! :)  How can i change the values of the button ? when the DIV 1 is being showed the value of the button is "1" and when 2nd Div is being shown the Value should be "2"

Answer (score 0):

So, from what I read, you just want to show one and hide the other? You can do that with `display` in css. Here is a way you can do that.

```
<div id="div1">One</div>
<div id="div2" style="display:none;">Two</div>
<button onClick="change_layer()">Change the Layer</button>


function change_layer(){
   document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("div2").style.display = "block";
}
```

You can also use JQuery, but if that is all you need to do, JQuery probably isn't needed. If you actually want them layered, you would have to use `z-index` in css.

Answer (score 0):

overlapping can be done by setting `position:relative` to div1 and having div2 as the child of div1. And set `position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; width:100%;` for div2.

```
<div id="div1">
   <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

javascript -

```
document.getElementById("div1").onclick = function(){
         //by "Div1 layer to go in the background" i assume you mean disappear or hide
         this.style.display = 'none';
         document.getElementById("div2").style.display = 'block';
};
```